# Trigger function when another function runs

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I'm working with jwplayer. I would like to use jwplayer().on('ready') which fires when the video player is ready. Normally the jwplayer() scripts load first, then I'd tell the client page to do something when the video player is ready eg. play ad. Unfortunately my scripts are being loaded first, so I can't reference the jwplayer().on('ready') command and I can't say do something when the player is loaded, because the client doesn't know what a the player is yet.

For example. I'd like to trigger a script once another function ("b") loads. I do not have access to the function b so I can't put in promises for something like .then . function b is a global variable so I can access it by window. Here is something that works.

```
    var num = Math.random() * 2000;
    setTimeout(function(){
        function b(){ 
            //b stuff
    }}, num);
```

-

```
    var counterA = 0;

    function bFind(){
        if(counterA <= 3000){
            //if (Object.keys(window).indexOf("b") != -1){ 
            if (window.hasOwnProperty("b") == true){
                //a stuff
                alert(counterA);
            }
            else{
                setTimeout(function(){
                    counterA += 5;
                    bFind();
                }, 5)
    }   }   }

    bFind();
```

I use Math.random to simulate that I don't know when this script is going to be loaded. Obviously this isn't optimal since I am checking the window every 5 ms. I have looked into .addEventListener('load',) but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. Is there another way to do this?

In this JSFiddle I can't set global variables so I've used obj in the place of window.

```js
var num = Math.random() * 2000;

var obj = {a: ""};

setTimeout(function(){
 obj = {
       a: ["hello","world"],
       b: ["foo","bar"]
 };
}, num);

/*_____________________________________*/

var counterA = 0;

function bFind(){
    if(counterA <= 3000){
        //if (Object.keys(obj).indexOf("b") != -1){ 
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty("b") == true){
   document.write(counterA);
        }
        else{
            setTimeout(function(){
                counterA += 100;
                document.write("_");
                bFind();
            }, 100)
}   }   }

bFind();
```

Comment: well the math.random code is not going to work because the function is declared inside that scope of the function and not window.... It would have to be `window.b = function() {}`

Comment: no there is no way to exactly do what you want, but you can always get your script with ajax request modify it and use eval on the modified code instead of just import the script.

Comment: please don't do (Object.keys(obj).indexOf("b")  just do if(obj.b) or obj.hasownproperty('b')

Comment: How are the scripts loaded? If the script containing `b()` is loaded first and then your script (i.e., they're loaded via two separate script tags), there shouldn't be any problem. If the scripts are concatenated, then it seems like your initial approach is okay. You could also use something like RequireJS.

Comment: Why do you need this?
It looks like [The XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Blurp the scripts containing b() are loaded after mine.

Comment: Can you control the ordering of script loading? It's usually preferable to load dependencies first.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I'm working with jwplayer. I would like to use jwplayer().on('ready') which fires when the video player is ready. Normally the jwplayer() scripts load first, then I'd tell the client page to do something when the video player is ready eg. play ad. Unfortunately my scripts are being loaded first, so I can't reference the jwplayer().on('ready') command and I can't say do something when the player is loaded, because the client doesn't know what a the player is yet.

Comment: @Blurp no unfortunately... :/

Answer (score 0):

In fact if the global variable is created by you you can detect when it change

```
~function(){
    var hiddenValue;
    Object.defineProperty(window, "myGlobalVar", {
        set: function (x) {
            hiddenValue = x
            console.log("value has changed")
        },
        get: function(x){
            return hiddenValue
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
}()

myGlobalVar = 9
```